# Periodic background task in Blazor wasm

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

In Blazor wasm, I would like to periodically execute a job (code),
even if the user is navigating through the pages (every x min for example).

Is that possible? What would be a practical way?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFQ5Vzf3dGQ

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Create a Service to manage the timer**

```cs
public class JobExecutedEventArgs : EventArgs {}


public class PeriodicExecutor : IDisposable
{
    public event EventHandler<JobExecutedEventArgs> JobExecuted;
    void OnJobExecuted()
    {
        JobExecuted?.Invoke(this, new JobExecutedEventArgs());
    }

    Timer _Timer;
    bool _Running;

    public void StartExecuting()
    {
        if (!_Running)
        {
            // Initiate a Timer
            _Timer= new Timer();
            _Timer.Interval = 300_000;  // every 5 mins
            _Timer.Elapsed += HandleTimer;
            _Timer.AutoReset = true;
            _Timer.Enabled = true;

            _Running = true;
        }
    }
    void HandleTimer(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Execute required job

        // Notify any subscribers to the event
        OnJobExecuted();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_Running)
        {
            // Clear up the timer
        }
    }
}
```

**Register it in Program.cs**

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<PeriodicExecutor>();
```

**Request it and start it in home page initialization**

```cs
@page "/home"
@inject PeriodicExecutor PeriodicExecutor

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        PeriodicExecutor.StartExecuting();
    }
}
```

**In any component if you want to do something when job executes**

```cs
@inject PeriodicExecutor PeriodicExecutor
@implements IDisposable

<label>@JobNotification</label>

@code {

   protected override void OnIntiialized()
   {
       PeriodicExecutor.JobExecuted += HandleJobExecuted;
   }
   public void Dispose()
   {
       PeriodicExecutor.JobExecuted -= HandleJobExecuted;
   }

   string JobNotification;
   void HandleJobExecuted(object sender, JobExecutedEventArgs e)
   {
        JobNotification = $"Job Executed: {DateTime.Now}";
        StateHasChanged();
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to start it on the page you can start it in Startup, like the comment below by Jason D. You can also use that to start a Scoped BackgroundService - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service

Comment: Will this continue to work if the user navigates away to a different screen and app stays idle?

Comment: Not guaranteed.  AFAIK, when a browser window is left idle then, dependent on the browser, the processing of JS in the WebAssembly will be throttled.  However, as soon as the window is activated again (browser tab selected) then the timer will kick in again at full speed.

Comment: @NoumanQaiser yes, it will. You can insert a Console message a watch on console window. Console.WriteLine("HandleTimer "+counter);

Answer (score 4):

If you are using an ASP.NET Core Hosted flavor of Blazor WebAssembly, you can use a BackgroundService.  For example:

**MyBackgroundService.cs**

```c#
public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<CollectionService> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public MyBackgroundService(ILogger<CollectionService> logger, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("My Background Service is starting.");

        //Do your work here...
```

**Startup.cs**

```c#
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<MyBackgroundService>();
    services.AddHostedService(provider => provider.GetService<MyBackgroundService>());
```

One benefit of this solution is the service will start running regardless of whether a user navigates to any particular page on the site.  Or even if no user access the site.

Comment: This doesn't work on WebAssembly, does it?

Comment: Good point!  My app is an api hosted wasm app (so my code runs on the server side).  If the user is implementing a front-end only (not web api hosted), then this won't work.

Comment: `IDisposable` is redundant since `BackgroundService` already implements it

Comment: Thanks Aamir.  I updated the code example based on your feedback.

Answer (score 3):

You can treat  MainLayout.razor or App.razor as 'normal pages' for this.

Use MainLayout when you have something to show on screen:

#### MainLayout.razor

```
.... 
<div>Time=@theTime</div>

@code
{
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Ticker();
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    string theTime;

    // use an async-void or a timer. An async-void needs no cleanup. 
    async void Ticker()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(2_000);
            theTime = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

            StateHasChanged();   // refresh everything
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: .net 6 `PeriodicTimer` will make this better :)

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way within a Blazor component would be to create a `Timer`, subscribe to `Elapsed`, and call `InvokeAsync` to update any state:

```cs
// In a @code block, or a Component.razor.cs file:
private readonly Timer _jobTimer = new() 
{
    AutoReset = true,
    Enabled = true,
    Interval = 60000, // 1 minute
};

protected override void OnInitialized() {
    _jobTimer.Elapsed += JobMethod; 
    // ^ don't forget to unsubscribe and dispose in IDisposable.Dispose!
}

private async void JobMethod(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    // do extraneous stuff here
    await InvokeAsync(() => {
        // update state here
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
    // however you implement this, but at the very least least:
    _jobTimer.Elapsed -= JobMethod;
    _jobTimer.Dispose();
}
```

Use this if the job is localized to a single component. For reusability, prefer [Neil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67619219/6789816).

Comment: If it is localized, also dispose the timer.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant but I guess it wasn't clear from my comment. Also, fixed the subscription line, which was wrong.