# Send Mail With Blazor Before Page Loading

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

Hi I am totally newbie about .NET Core blazor. I have a standing (running) application.I want to check some situations and send mail to the user every day.
but I don't want to use the OnInitializedAsync() function for this because I want to check and send mail even if the user does not open the page. Is there any way to do something like this.

Comment: Hi, I think you need check the official document and follow the tutorial to create a background services and no need write any code in OnInitializedAsync(). Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

You could create a service that periodically performs a task in blazor. An example can be found here: [Periodic background task in Blazor wasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67619072/periodic-background-task-in-blazor-wasm)