# Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost:7123" from accessing a cross-origin frame. Blazor Webassembly while trying to access iframe element

Tags: iframe, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In my Blazor Webassembly website I've included the possibility to subscribe to a newsletter. Subscribing is working well. I get a notification and after double-opt-in I'm in the subscribers list.

```
<div class="container g-padding-y-80--xs g-padding-y-125--sm" id="subscriptionContainer">
<iframe id="subscription" @onload="IFrameLoaded" src="https://someserver.sibforms.com/serve/..." frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

What I need to do now is check if the success element, with `id="success-message"` is showing up (`display = block;`).

To do that I've written some javascript code, which I run `OnAfterRenderAsync`

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("checkIfSuccess", null);
    }
}
```

The js code I'm referring to is:

```
    function checkIfSuccess() {

    var frameObj = document.getElementById('subscription');
    var frameContent = frameObj.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
}
```

While trying to do so, I'm getting the following error:

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost:7123" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
  Error: Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost:7123" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

I have now 2 questions:

1. How can I solve that? My app is a client-side only app (Blazor Webassembly).
2. Once solved, how can I get notified, that my element with `with id="success-message"` is now visible? What I've implemented so far is a Periodic background task according to this great [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67619072/periodic-background-task-in-blazor-wasm). In this way I can run my javascript code each second. The periodic background task is also working well.

Many thanks for any help.